# Override CSS with Chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, overriding, code-injection

Is there any option, how to hardly override css on web page? I successfully inject css into page, but my stylesheet is overrided by page one.

I also tried **!important;** in my css, but it doesnt work.

my manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Test",
"version": "0.1",


"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
"*://www.test.com/*"
],
  "css": ["blue.css"],
  "run_at": "document_start"
}
],

"permissions": [
  "*://www.test.com/*"
],

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png"
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Use css selector priority like using id or just give `!important`.
You can check priority rules [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Can you try to add '!important' near by the css value? I hope it will work. Cool !

Comment: I tied !important; but it doesnt work (edited post).

Comment: Try `body .tblOdds .sate`

Comment: body .tblOddes .rate and !important combination works!! thank you very much

Comment: @medy75 Great. good luck.

Comment: Maybe overkill but if doing this a lot, try using a postcss plugin like postcss-safe-importantly to add important!. Also check up on https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/ - I'd argue that injecting custom-styled elements into pages with a Chrome extension is a good use of !important since otherwise it's a pain

Answer (score 0):

The solution is posted in comments, just making it visible here:

@Alex

> Try `body .tblOdds .sate`

@medy75 (author)

> body .tblOddes .rate and !important combination works!! thank you very much

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).